# What about $CT$ or $PT$ violations?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, symmetry-breaking, weak-interaction

In particle physics, $CPT$ is a universal conservation law.
This implies that any combination of only two of them should be violated in some processes.
The only one I heard of so far is the $CP$ violation. But what about the other two possible combinations ($CT$ and $PT$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been obvious for the most part of modern science history that $CT$ isn't a fundamental symmetry. For example gravity acts the same on matter and antimatter. So a charged particle in free fall violates $CT$. The same can be said about $PT$: The fact that particles possess [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)) violates $PT$. These two violations are thus probably too trivial to still receive much attention today.

But for a long time, there was indeed no evidence of $CP$ violation, which only became apparent in some weak decays, which took until the mid of the 20th century until scientist had the know-how and instrumentation to study weak decays with some level of detail.

$CP$ violation is still in discussion today, because it is an open question whether $CP$ is *also* violated by other forces than the weak force.

Comment: @ric.san Yes a positive charge moving left is $CT$ symmetric to a negative charge moving right, **but processes exist** which make both negative and positive charges move in the same direction, e.g. gravity.

Comment: Thinking about it, free fall could really violate $CT$ symmetry. A positively charged particle in free fall starts with $v(t=0)=0$ and then its velocity $v(t)$ increases as time passes by. After applying $CT$ I see a negatively charged particle with an initial velocity $v(t=0)\neq0$ that progressively comes to a halt. So these two scenarios are clearly not equivalent... am I right, or is there something missing?

Comment: @ric.san Your mental visualization of these falling particles is correct, as far as I can tell. A (down)falling negative particles looks like a downfalling negative particle. And in contrast, a downfalling positive particle after $CT$ looks like an *up*falling negative particle. Not the same, as you noticed.